# Error in xgboost() in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to use xgboost(), but I am getting following error:

```
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label) : can not open file "0"

If I traceback,

traceback()
4: .Call("XGDMatrixCreateFromFile_R", data, as.integer(FALSE), PACKAGE = "xgboost")
3: xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label)
2: xgb.get.DMatrix(data, label)
1: xgboost(data = as.matrix(trainSet[, 1:13]), label = trainSet[, 
"count"], max.depth = depth, nround = rounds, objective = "reg:linear", 
verbose = 0) at #5
```

Any reason why I am getting the above error. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the class/structure/content of your `data` variable?

Answer (score 5):

Check if your data has character or factor variables and try to convert them to numerical.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. XGBoost does not accept factor inputs